# download file from url with qt - ssl error

Tags: c++, qt, download

For my scientific C++ software, I need to automatically download a couple of files from the internet. 
I'm already using QT for the GUI development, so I tried to implement the download with Qt as well.

Please mind that I do not have a network or programming background. 
I'm quite surprised how complex it seems to be to download a file with C++. 
In MATLAB I would simply use a function called [websave](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/websave.html) like that:

```
file = 'https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
filename = websave('google.png',file);
```

I found a C++ [example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/network/download?h=5.13) in Qt (source code is below) which should do it.
Unfortunately, I did not get it to run. 
I always get the following error messages, even from the official Qt example source code:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_free_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_new_null
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_push
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_ex_new_index
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
We got a connection error when networkLayerState is Unknown
Download of https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png failed: Error creating SSL context ()
```

Questions: What are those `ssl-errors` and more importantly, how can I implement a proper download of a file given by a URL in C++ (with Qt)? 
Since I do not understand the error and I cannot debug it properly, I do not know how to start to fix it.

(the application has to run on Windows and Linux)

This is a simplified version of the Qt example where I tried to download the google logo. 
The full example can be found [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/network/download?h=5.13)

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtNetwork>

#include <cstdio>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QSslError;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

using namespace std;

class DownloadManager: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QVector<QNetworkReply *> currentDownloads;

public:
    DownloadManager();
    void doDownload(const QUrl &url);
    bool saveToDisk(const QString &filename, QIODevice *data);
    static bool isHttpRedirect(QNetworkReply *reply);

public slots:
    void execute();
    void downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
    void sslErrors(const QList<QSslError> &errors);
};

DownloadManager::DownloadManager()
{
    connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void DownloadManager::execute()
{
    QString file = "https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    QUrl url = file;
    doDownload(url);
}

void DownloadManager::doDownload(const QUrl &url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

#if QT_CONFIG(ssl)
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
            SLOT(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
#endif

    currentDownloads.append(reply);
}

void DownloadManager::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QUrl url = reply->url();
    if (reply->error()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Download of %s failed: %s\n",
                url.toEncoded().constData(),
                qPrintable(reply->errorString()));
    } else {
        if (isHttpRedirect(reply)) {
            fputs("Request was redirected.\n", stderr);
        } else {

            QString path = url.path();
            QString filename = QFileInfo(path).fileName();
            if (saveToDisk(filename, reply)) {
                printf("Download of %s succeeded (saved to %s)\n",
                       url.toEncoded().constData(), qPrintable(filename));
            }
        }
    }

    currentDownloads.removeAll(reply);
    reply->deleteLater();

    if (currentDownloads.isEmpty()) {
        // all downloads finished
        QCoreApplication::instance()->quit();
    }
}

bool DownloadManager::saveToDisk(const QString &filename, QIODevice *data)
{
    QFile file(filename);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s for writing: %s\n",
                qPrintable(filename),
                qPrintable(file.errorString()));
        return false;
    }

    file.write(data->readAll());
    file.close();

    return true;
}

bool DownloadManager::isHttpRedirect(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    return statusCode == 301 || statusCode == 302 || statusCode == 303
           || statusCode == 305 || statusCode == 307 || statusCode == 308;
}


void DownloadManager::sslErrors(const QList<QSslError> &sslErrors)
{
#if QT_CONFIG(ssl)
    for (const QSslError &error : sslErrors)
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL error: %s\n", qPrintable(error.errorString()));
#else
    Q_UNUSED(sslErrors);
#endif
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    DownloadManager manager;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, &manager, SLOT(execute()));

    app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Looks like Qt can't find the SSL libraries it needs. Older Qt versions used OpenSSL, I believe 15.3+ has a different solution now (at least on Windows/MSVC).  Post your version or Google with something like "qt ssl library" or such.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.11.2

Comment: Here's [one article](https://www.blikoontech.com/networking/how-to-get-rid-of-ssl-warnings-in-qt-applications-qsslsocket-cannot-resolve-tlsv1_1_client_method-warnings) specifically for 5.11, though it's WIndows-focused. Essentially you need to get the correct OpenSSL libraries and put them where Qt and your application can find them (either in Qt install `bin` folder and/or in your app's runtime root folder).

Comment: Thanks, what would be an alternative solution instead of using Qt which is portable and easy? (is there a boost equivalent?)

Comment: For the download part or your whole app?  The base issue with SSL is that all crypto software is under export restrictions in the US. That's why Qt doesn't ship with those libs anymore (they used to). And there aren't many SSL library choices out there (if any, besides OpenSSL). So pretty much "anything" that needs HTTPS access is going to use OpenSLL libs. Note this is only an issue for HTTPS, non-encrypted network access doesn't need SSL, naturally.

Comment: just the download part. How would a solution without SSL look like? Maybe it is sufficient for me.

Comment: Just use http URLs if you can (not https). The Google image is a bad example because AFAIK Google enforces encrypted https access.

Comment: Great, the problem disappeared by simply changing `https` to `http`. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Easier than chasing down library versions, for sure!  :)